# C# function call never reaches first line of executable code, only on a particular pc

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a piece of code that creates a new SQL-Server Express Database, and then runs a predefined table generation/population script.  Its a pretty straight forward and simple task, and the code works wonderfully under normal operations.  On one of our testing machines, this creation function stalls after creating the DB,  but before populating it.
It simply hangs with no error message, no deadlock (ui still responsive), and no CPU usage.

Further investigation and debugging determines that the line immediately before the LoadDatabaseTables() function call is executed, but the first line inside LoadDatabaseTables() is never reached. How exactly can a function be called, but then have the program fail to execute even the first line of the function?

The code in question is written in C#:

```
    ...snip...
    bool success=false;
    try
    {
        //...code that creates db, working as intended...
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        //...error handling...
    }
    finally
    {
        //Params is a locally defined struct, containing int, bool, and string members
        if(CreateScript(Params))  //generates appropriate script successfully, returns true
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("About to enter load script");
            if(LoadDatabaseTables(Params))
            {
               success=true;
            }
        }
    }
    return success;
}

private bool LoadDatabaseTables(DatabaseParams Params)
{
    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Entered the load script");
    bool success = false;
    Server server = null;
    try
    {
        //...sql calls...
        success = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //...exception handling...
    }
    return success;
}
...snip...
```

The first message "About to enter load script" is reached but the "Entered the load script" is not displayed, and the rest of the function does not execute, no exceptions are raised, nothing is returned.

Unfortunately, this machine does not have the necessary tools/licenses to run full debugging, and the problem only occurs on this one machine.  The message boxes obviously are not included in the regular version of the code, and a just being used to attempt to diagnose the problem.  The code executes normally on other systems with and without these message boxes.

Has anyone come across this kind of error before?  Any help would be most appreciated!

Comment: I don't think you've supplied enough details. What does your exception handling do? Did you trace through? It appears the function is failing so what is your code doing to handle that failure?

Comment: Also, it seems unlikely that running code that can fail within your `finally` block is the best approach.

Comment: I'd suggest using a proper logger over spawning UI to track the state of your app. This can be done easily with nlog/log4net. Nuget is your friend.

Comment: If the machine can run C#, then it has the necessary tools for debugging.

Comment: @Jonathan Wood: Exception handling in both redacted sections prints to a log file the exception state and location.  The log file has no new entries.  I agree that the finally block shouldnt contain code that can fail, but that is not my decision to make.  I didn't write this code, I am only tasked with fixing this problem.  If it doesn't directly solve this problem, I can't fix it.

Comment: @spender I would love to, but the logging tools we have in place (sadly only basic file io) are what we have to work with.  The log files were not showing anything, so I used the UI spawning to see if perhaps it was the logging itself that was having problems.

Comment: @RemusRusanu Thanks for the input! Would you care to elaborate?

Comment: @JasonHopkins: .Net 2.0 [MDbg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229861(v=vs.80).aspx), .Net 4.0 [MDbg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229861(v=vs.100).aspx), [SOS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764.aspx)+Windbg

Comment: MDBG deployment is a [3 file xcopy process](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2005/06/03/mdbgcore.aspx)

Comment: Found a solution to the problem, and wanted to share in case anyone else comes across this kind of issue.  There was an unhandled exception being thrown by the LoadDatabaseTables() function that was accidentally suppressed by the logger we had in place.  Once the real source of the error was visible (wrong version of an external assembly), it was simple to fix.  Apparently, C# will attempt to load any assemblies referenced by the function as soon as the function call happens. This failure was how the function could be called successfully, but then fail before the first executable line.